# Avoiding Delay from One View Controller to Another in Xcode using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have set up a button in my iOS App that performs segue from 1st View Controller to 2nd View Controller. But, there is a delay of about 3-5 seconds on moving from 1st View Controller to 2nd View Controller. Is there any way by which this delay can be avoided and the user can easily go to the 2nd View Controller on the click of the button without any delay? Would appreciate it if anyone could provide any suggestions on how can I eliminate this issue? Thanks a lot for the help:)

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "1to2segue", sender: self)

}
```

The 2nd View Controller displays live stats extracted from an external source. Thus, it takes time to load up. How can I make this process faster?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()

}
```

Comment: If you have a delay, that's not from there. I guess you are blocking the main thread instead somewhere else.

Comment: Add it to main thread.

Comment: Since In the second view Controller, the data is extracted from an external server to show live stats, thus it takes time to load up the 2nd View Controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second view controller, do ***NOT*** call your `loadData()` func in `viewDidLoad()`.

You want to do as little as needed to get the view on the screen. Show a spinner or some other "Loading Data..." activity view.

***Then***, perhaps in `viewDidAppear()`, call your `loadData()` func. But make sure whatever you're doing in `loadData()` is being done in an async process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have done exactly as mentioned above.Now the 2nd View Controller is loaded without any delay,but, the data in it the Vew Controller takes some time to load up. Could please explain me why is this happening. Thanks!

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 - I have absolutely *no idea* what data you're loading, how you're loading it, what you're doing with it, etc. If, for example, you're downloading 500 records from a database on a remote server, that will likely take some time. You could quicken that by downloading only the first, say, 20 records, then loading 20 more as needed. But again, I have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: Right! I guess for now I will use an activity loader in the view controller until it loads up the data from the server! Appreciate your time and effort!